# How to create a simple website that turns user submitted images into text using Google Vertext AI Vision API

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, ocr

I'm trying build a simple html/css/jquery website that turns user submitted images into text using Google Vertext AI Vision API (or other service).

I'd really appreciate if someone can answer the following.

1. How difficult is to create this website?
2. Any examples, tutorials that I can reference?

Thanks.

I tried finding examples and tutorials but couldn't find any.

Comment: The question you asked is too generic. We do not help build websites but we can help with specific problems. Please follow the [Stackoveflow: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can get proper help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "user submitted images into text". But if you are referring to OCR (Optical Character Recognition) you can look at:

[Github | Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)

[Github | TesseractJS](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js)

[Github | TesseractWASM](https://github.com/robertknight/tesseract-wasm)